# Is there an authoritative resource on generally accepted LaTeX usage standards (or at least generally accepted best practices)?

Tags: best-practices

I have been basically "hacking" with LaTeX so far, trying out things that seem to visually give the result I want, and using google to find solutions.

However, I have heard people say that certain LaTeX usage is bad (e.g. using `:` instead of `\colon` in certain places), and that certain packages are canonical (e.g. `amsmath`).

Other questions have asked about an [ad hoc list of best practices](https://web.archive.org/web/20140810161750/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193298/best-practices-in-latex), or about the [LaTeX language specification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275330/is-there-a-language-standard-iso-ansi-for-latex), but my question is: **Are there LaTeX usage standards that are basically accepted by the mainstream researcher community (and in particular, journals and conferences) as "the correct" way to use LaTeX, and that are organized into a single resource?** I don't expect literally all usage standards to be in there, since different fields might have different expectations or customs. One candidate I found is the [Math into Latex book by Gratzer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387322892).

Comment: Short answer: no. There are things more users would agree on, and some which less users find acceptable.

Comment: There are basically accepted deprecated  usages (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348453/list-of-deprecated-commands-and-their-appreciated-alternatives/348466)) but d don't be surprised to find them in journal and conference templates.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Do you worry that a journal or conference might reject your (camera-ready) submission because you didn't follow standards? In that case: there are people with the task of sanitizing submissions, either in the LaTeX source or in postprocessing, so non-standard tricks will be filtered out there. Or are you generally just interested in 'clean' coding? In that case using LaTeX in general will give you a hard time :)

Comment: The only thing I think most people might agree on is things that *shouldn't* be done.  I'm collecting examples, and hope to write up an overview.  (In my copious free time.)

Comment: Also, correct usage for one journal is not the same as correct usage for another.  One general hint: If they have gone to some effort to prevent you from doing something, don't do it.

Comment: @Marijn, "*In that case: there are people with the task of sanitizing submissions, either in the LaTeX source or in postprocessing*" Do you mean people working at the journal, or people one can hire?

Comment: @user56834 people working at the journal.